# Concatenate contant on static var

Tags: php

I've got a class which works perfectly on localhost (PHP 5.6.10),

```
class Blog
{
    static $table = DBPREFIX . '_blog';

    // SELECTs
    static function getAll()
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM '.self::$table.' WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY ord';
        return R::getRow($query);
    }
}
```

But when I put it in the server (PHP 5.5.27) it gives me an error on the static var because I'm concatenating the contant,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in
>   /models/Blog.php on line 3

Can anyone tell me which is the configuration that it's going wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: I've edited the question, I only had that comma because the query was larger, I just shortened it to make it easier to read

Comment: `php` states `Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed.`

Comment: sure, but why does it even work on localhost? must be some configuration on the php.ini right?

Comment: Might be E_STRICT  mode

Comment: Dynamic definitions (allowing the use of operations) for class properties was introduced in PHP version 5.6.0

Comment: Oh, ok, did not know that, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic definitions (allowing the use of operations) for class properties was introduced in PHP version 5.6.0

So a class property definition of

```
static $table = DBPREFIX . '_blog';
```

which uses the concatenation operator is valid in PHP >= 5.6.0 but not valid in earlier versions of PHP

**EDIT**

See the [PHP 5.6 Changelog](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) for details

Comment: so in order to do this I really do need to use the __construct() and can't use it as a static right?

Comment: Or you need to upgrade your server to 5.6 if possible.... PHP 5.5 is now only in security updates for another 10 months before it reaches end of life